# Can I apply for a Schengen visa if I invest my salary into mutual funds rather than keeping it in my bank account?

Tags: schengen, belgium, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am an Indian national. I am planning to apply for 3 days visit visa for Belgium. The visit purpose is a Job Interview. Employer will reimburse the cost of air tickets, Taxis and accommodation. But initially I have to pay for all. I have already made booking for return air tickets, accommodation myself.

As per visa guidelines I need to show means of subsistence. I do not keep money in my bank account. I am employed in India. I pay home loans, car loans and whatever is left, I invest in Equity Mutual funds. Thus after 15 of every month I am left with very little money in my account. Current value of my mutual funds investment is about Rs.300000 (About 4000 euro).

Is it must to have money in Bank account? Can I show investments as a proof of subsistence? If required I can liquidate part of my investment in 1-2 days time. But I do not want to unless necessary.

Can I show my credit card also? I am aware according to visa guidelines I need daily approx. 50 euro. Thus I would need to show at least 150 euros.

Comment: I am no expert on this topic, but the fact that you have already booked (and paid) the return ticket is a strong advantage point for you. Having a CC for three days would probably suffice.

Answer (score 2):

**Legal view:**

[Article 21](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810) of the Visa Code doesn't require the funds to be in cash particularly.

> 21.5) The means of subsistence for the intended stay shall be assessed in
>   accordance with the duration and the purpose of the stay and by
>   reference to average prices in the Member State(s) concerned for board
>   and lodging in budget accommodation, multiplied by the number of days
>   stayed, on the basis of the reference amounts set by the Member States
>   in accordance with Article 34(1)(c) of the Schengen Borders Code.
>   Proof of sponsorship and/or private accommodation may also constitute
>   evidence of sufficient means of subsistence.

**Practical view:**

The practice may vary from one country/case to another, but you should consider that the process is for risk assessment at all. A person, who has mutual funds equivalent to 4000 euro, is expected to have less risk of illegal immigration than who has 150 euro cash only. Of course I can't guarantee what happens, but I wouldn't look for cash in your case.

Providing credit card statement is a plus. You can provide any extra document to lower the risk even if it is not requested by the consulate/embassy.